# Where does request.user come from in Parse Server

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

I'm trying to port my Parse.com app to Parse server.

According to the Parse migration guide, Parse.User.current() can no longer be used and instead you should fetch the current user via 'request.user'.

However, request.user is always undefined for me.

For example, when I successfully login a user and then redirect to another path (/mypath), the incoming request at mypath does not contain a user object.

```
Parse.User.logIn(username, password, {
  success: function(user) {
    res.redirect('/mypath');
  }
})

// Index of the /mypath controller
exports.index = function(request, response) {
    // request.user is undefined here
}
```

How do I work with the active user after I logged in sucessfully?

Answer (score 4):

I think I figured it out.

When working in Cloud Code there is no magic request.user. Rather when logging in you need to manually store the user info in the current session. In the Parse.com days this would've been managed by the parse-express-cookie-session middleware. This is explained in the [cloud code guide](https://parse.com/docs/cloudcode/guide). With Parse-Server you can insert your own middleware to manage the user as is described [here](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues/497).

However, the request.user will be available when receiving requests from a client SDK using an authenticated user.